# How to apply if/then statements to refute/assert methods

Tags: ruby, boolean

## TDD

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'
require_relative 'light'

class LightTest < Minitest::Test
 def test_light_is_off
  light = Light.new
  refute light.on?
 end

 def test_turn_light_on

  light = Light.new
  light.turn_on
  assert light.on?
 end
end
```

## CODE

```
class Light

 def on?
  false
 end

 def turn_on
  true
 end
end
```

I know this is very basic as far as trying to get the test to pass but what am I missing?

So basically it's saying, the light is initially off, then after you define and call on the turn_on method, the light should be on. So, the first test should be false, and the 2nd test should be true after the method is run.

For some reason, I don't know how to go about putting that into code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive, rather than just repeating the information you've already made available in tags. If you remove the tag info (Ruby and Boolean), it leaves your entire title as *Exercise*, which is totally meaningless. Your title should explain a specific problem or question in a way that will have meaning to a future reader here who sees it  in a list of search results. And when you make that [edit] to improve the title, stop SHOUTING and use your shift key properly. Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate the advice about the description and opinion about the title

Comment: I'm assuming this is some form of homework, so rather than telling you the answer, I'm hoping that people will take something of a Socratic approach.  Your test seems to be centered on the on? method.  Right now it looks like your "on" method only returns one thing.  How do you hold "state" in ruby?

Comment: set an instance variable? or initialize an object so that it has state? I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Since the light is going to start in some state, maybe you could set that initial state in an instance variable from an initialize method.  Could you get your first test to pass based on the value that you set in the initialize method instead of hard  coding "false"?

Comment: class Light
     attr_reader :light,
                        :turn_on

     def initialize
      (at)light = false
      (at)turn_on = true
    end

     def on?
      (at)light == turn_on
     end
   end

Comment: Something like that? setting light = false?

Comment: You're welcome, but it wasn't an opinion about the title. It's a requirement of this site according to the guidelines. I've removed the redundant tag information you left in your title after the edit; once again, it is not necessary to redundantly repeat tag information in the title of your post. The tag system works extremely well here, and doesn't need assistance. Thanks for your edit of the remainder. :-)

Comment: @murphlee85 - I think you may be over defining your state.  You seem to be defining two instance variables, whereas it seems like your light state should be either on or off.  Your on? method should be returning the instance variable (which will be true or false).  Your turn_on method should probably be setting the instance variable to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light state is, well, state of the object.

In Ruby, object state is kept in instance variables.

Initial state is set in the initializer.

Here's your complete `Light` class:

```
class Light
  def initialize
    @light = false
  end

  def on?
    @light
  end

  def off?
    !on?
  end

  def turn_on
    @light = true
  end

  def turn_off
    @light = false
  end
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. Besides the adding the attr_reader up top for light, the tests pass even if we take the off? method and turn_off method out. I believe the 2 methods left address the tests by initially addressing that the light is off and then we reassign the instance variable of light to true after you run the turn_on method

Comment: I have added off methods for completeness. For the class to be universally useful.